# Tweaking fonts in algorithms

Tags: fonts, algorithmicx

I'm working on a problem set for my algorithms course and just started using the `algorithm` and `algorithmicx` packages to produce pseudocode. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to give DETECT-CYCLE in line 3 the same font as in line 5? I looked through the docs for the packages I mentioned, and I haven't seen a way to do this.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a call to a function/procedure use

```
\Call{<function>}{<parms>}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \Function{Something}{$G$, $e$}
    \State \ldots
    \State \Call{Something else}{$G$, $e$}
  \EndFunction
  \State
  \Function{Something else}{$G$, $e$}
    \While{true}
      \State \ldots
    \EndWhile
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}​
```

Here is the definition of `\Function` and `\Call` in [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty):

```
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
   [2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
\algnewcommand\Call[2]{\textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
```

Note how both calls use `\textproc` to format the function/procedure. In a pinch, you can therefore use `\textproc{<function>}` to achieve the appropriate formatting.